# what makes the discharging energy of the capacitor is higher than that already has been charged?

Tags: capacitor, charging

[image]

these curves illustrates the capacitor charging and discharging periods its charging until time 0.037, after that the discharging period will began, as its clear the discharging has more power than charging

Comment: The graphs don't even have units, also have you heard of integral?

Comment: I'm not sure that "its clear the discharging has more power than charging". To me it seems that the power is roughly the same

Comment: Energy and power are not the same thing - "what makes the discharging **energy** of the capacitor is higher than that already has been charged?"  ... "as its clear the discharging has more **power** than charging"

Comment: its taken direct from matlab print screen and it has the label of V, I , P of the capacitor so what you need of units?? @PlasmaHH

Comment: it is clear, you can focus on the value of current and power on x axis, for y axis its obvious for the timing! @frarugi87

Comment: good to know that! @JImDearden

Comment: sorry, I was speaking about the energy, and I did not notice that you wrote power meaning, well, power. In any case the energy is maintained, not the power. A simpler example is this one: you give me 1$ each day for 30 days, then the 31st day I'll give you 30$. The instantaneous amount (the power) I give you is greater than what you gave me during the time, but the total amount of money (energy) is the same

Answer (score 2):

Label your graphs, label your axis and add units, then you stand a better chance of understanding why your pictures look wrong.

There is not more energy discharged then charged into the capacitor. If you integrate (add up the space between the line and the x-axis) you'll see they are about the same. Any difference between them will be due to differences in starting and ending states of the capacitor and losses in the system due to heat or through the test probes etc.

Comment: its labeled , Vc ,Ic, Pc. Vs time, and the difference is clear, the power arise from 3.7kw to -9 kw

Comment: The answer is above, if you can understand it.  You are looking at values over time, and comparing them to instantaneous values.  There is a difference you know.

Comment: @AbdulhamidSaad this is like a barrel was at first filled slowly (=with low power) and then overturned to get a high power splash.